# Avoid Angular2 to systematically submit form on button click

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, submit

Ok so maybe this is unclear. Get this form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #crisisForm="ngForm">
   <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="crisis.name">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   <button type="button" (click)="preview()">Preview</button>
   <button type="reset" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Why do all buttons trigger the `submit()` function ? And how to avoid that ?

Comment: return false; from your submit() function

Answer (score 259):

I see two options to solve it:

1) Specify **type="button"** explicitly (i think it's **more preferable**):

```
<button type="button" (click)="preview();">Preview</button>
```

According to W3 specification:

- http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.html

  > A button element **with**
  >   **no type attribute** **specified represents the same thing as a button**
  >   **element with its type attribute set to "submit"**.

2) Use `$event.preventDefault()`:

```
<button (click)="preview(); $event.preventDefault()">Preview</button>
```

or

```
<button (click)="preview($event);">Preview</button>

preview(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('preview')
}
```

Comment: `(click)="preview(); false"` should do the same. For example `stopPropagation()` would need to be called explicitely, but if an event handler returns `false`, then `preventDefault` is called on the event.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thanks very much for pointing this out! Firstly i tried it but i wrote `return false` and it didn't work :)

Comment: `return` is probably not allowed in binding expressions but the the value of the last expression is returned implicitly.

Comment: Using #2 seems the best answer. Just adding: type="button" to my button solved the problem

Comment: In the second example, it seems that the comma is quite necessary after the method called by the event. I had problems without it and had to leave it there

Comment: In this case, I need to pass $event in here too. <form (submit)="func($event)">.
Why that is needed?

Comment: I didn't know about `type=button` W3C's spec. Thank you!!

Answer (score 18):

[**This Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1KSK1ICIVDtsOianWuN?p=preview) suggests otherwise, every button seem to work as intended.

However, to prevent default behaviour of the form you can do this,

---

**TS:**

```
submit(e){
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Template:**

```
<form (submit)="submit($event)" #crisisForm="ngForm">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the plnkr... It's all about the button type http://plnkr.co/edit/BKIqcz7aKBFQDZioZ5Fy

Comment: indeed ! it is.  and you have defined on all the buttons, so it was working as intended

Answer (score 17):

You have to import FormsModule from '@angular/forms' in your app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
 ],
 })
```

Comment: That's the right answer, all others are hacky non angular like uneeded workarounds.

Comment: perfect angular way can't agree more.

Answer (score 8):

I found that with 2.0 release `(ngSubmit)` is passing a `null` event value to the method so instead you should us `(submit)`

```
<form (submit)="submit($event)" #crisisForm="ngForm">
```

your .ts file

```
submit($event){
   /* form code */
   $event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, dont knwo why ngSubmit works when not used as a form group, but when I use it as a form group i have to use your solution

Comment: I gave this answer some time back when 2.0 just released, but after that angular 2 has came a long way so are you sure you are using the latest release version ?

Answer (score 6):

I has the same issue. The work around I found was the replace `button` with `a` and apply button style to anchor element:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #crisisForm="ngForm">
   <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="crisis.name">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   <a class="btn" (click)="preview()">Preview</a>
   <a class="btn" (click)="reset()">Reset</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

Set **type="button"** in the button that you don't want to execute submit.

Comment: That's sementically not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provide a built-in solution for this. You just need to replace the `(submit)="handleSubmit()"` with `(ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()"`. By doing this `e.preventDefault()` will be implicitly called by angular itself under the hood.