# Page reloads when using EventEmmiter

Tags: angular

I have a parent/child component setup. The parent has a button (Display Form) that will display the child component, and the child a button that hides the child component (Cancel).

When I push the cancel button, the form disappears but for some reason the page then reloads, any ideas why or how to prevent this?

This doesn't happen when I use the button in the parent to display, or hide the form, only if I use the button in the child.

Parent HTML

```
<div *ngIf="showContactDetail" class="panel-body">
    <app-contact-detail 
        (showContactDetail)='setShowContactDetail($event)'>
    </app-contact-detail>
</div>
```

Parent TS

```
setShowContactDetail(value: boolean) {
    this.showContactDetail = value;
}
```

Child HTML

```
 <button id="cancelContact" name="cancelContact" 
            class="btn btn-danger" (click)='cancelClicked()'>Cancel</button>
```

Child TS

```
@Output() showContactDetail: EventEmitter<boolean> =
    new EventEmitter<boolean>();

cancelClicked(): void {
    this.showContactDetail.emit(false);
}
```

Comment: Possible you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786995/avoid-angular2-to-systematically-submit-form-on-button-click

Comment: Thanks, that directed me to an answer, I needed to specify the button as type button