# Custom Validator throw error upon resetting reactive form in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I have a Data-Driven Form in angular 2.
And in one of the control i have a custom validator.
If i am using `this.myForm.reset()` while the control on which the validator has been applied having some value, the validator cracks up, and throws an error.

While if i'm not using `this.myForm.reset()` method anywhere, the custom validator works just great!

The custom validator uses a package installed by npm in the angular component.
The validator is as follows:

```
phoneNumberValidator (control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
   if (!validator.isMobilePhone((<string>control.value), 'en-IN')) {
     return {phoneNumberValidator: true};
   }
   return null;
}
```

And i'm using the validator as follows:

```
'phoneNumber': new FormControl('', [
     Validators.required,
     Validators.maxLength(14),
     this.phoneNumberValidator
])
```

Error message: [image: Error message]

As I've mentioned, the validator is working fine without `myform.reset()`
The npm package I'm using is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

I've tried to use ngForm, but i guess it is for Template-Driven forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `phoneNumberValidator` plugin that you're using needs `phoneNumber` control should have at least empty string. So you set up that value to empty string while resetting a form.

```
this.myForm.reset({'phoneNumber': ''})
//OR
//this.myForm.resetForm({'phoneNumber': ''})
```

Comment: its not a plugin. And what you suggested isn't working. The problem still persists.

Does the `reset()` method resets the form to the original (creation) state?
As i'm originally providing the form an empty string as here `'phoneNumber': new FormControl('', [`

Comment: @HimanshuMittal This should work. You're doing something wrong. When you call `reset` method angular reset value to `null`. This answer corrects that behaviour

Comment: @HimanshuMittal If you doubt then check this example https://plnkr.co/edit/nHuOG3rJfQb7JxXO1cCo?p=preview

Comment: Can you find my mistake please @yurzui, as i've checked and scratched everything to find it. My Component lives [here](https://github.com/mittal01091997/Final-Year-Project/tree/frontend/Client/src/app/Components/user-signup)
I did my commit before i saved my HTML changes, the HTML also follows the changes suggested by Pankaj

Comment: @HimanshuMittal You're calling reset without parameters. https://github.com/mittal01091997/Final-Year-Project/blob/frontend/Client/src/app/Components/user-signup/user-signup.component.html#L73

Comment: @yurzui thank you for helping with this. You're champ, Thanks again :)

Comment: @yurzui I did commited before saving the file, i have it in my project, but its not working. Can you testout my angular project please?

Comment: @HimanshuMittal I have already tested your project. Replace `(click)="loginForm.reset()"` with `(click)="loginForm.reset({'phoneNumber': ''})"`

Comment: Can you please commit the code with problem statement? We can help you further

Comment: I have pushed the missing statuement you guys were suggesting me in the Markup code, please copy the component [here](https://github.com/mittal01091997/Final-Year-Project/blob/frontend/Client/src/app/Components/user-signup) and test if for your self

Comment: @HimanshuMittal Remove `type="reset"` here https://github.com/mittal01091997/Final-Year-Project/blob/frontend/Client/src/app/Components/user-signup/user-signup.component.html#L73

Comment: Button should have either reset or button.

Comment: If you don't mention type on button it will be by default submit. Which ultimately calls ngSumbit method

Comment: Then set `type="button"` instead of `type="reset"` I forgot it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786995/avoid-angular2-to-systematically-submit-form-on-button-click/40103456#40103456

Comment: The reason why with reset it is not working is that angular subscribes to reset event https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L64 and therefore just calls form.reset without parameters https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L142